# Rails revoke token using doorkeeper gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using Doorkeeper gem with device to authenticate my rest api application calls.

While deleting the user, I am just inactivating the user in back-end database so I wanna to revoke access token while  I am deleting the account to prevent access by deleted user access token.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `POST /oauth/revoke` should do the job:

https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/wiki/API-endpoint-descriptions-and-examples#post-oauthrevoke

Comment: I actually used this to setup my doorkeeper authentication https://blog.yorkxin.org/posts/2013/11/05/oauth2-tutorial-grape-api-doorkeeper-en/ .   what should be inside this method to revoke the token ?